# jQuery: selecting element that has its ID starting with a given text

Tags: jquery

Given a table with the following id attribute:

```
id="table.form.address.48619"
```

... how can I select it given only the table.form.address portion of its id?

If I try the following :

```
    var sInputs = $('table[id=^"table\\.form\\.address"]');
alert( sInputs.html() );
```

I get a null

Thanks

PS - I got NO CONTROL over the way the ID gets generated :-(, it's just something I have to deal with

Comment: Why do you have the double backslashes in there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('table[id^="table.form.address"]');
```

`^=` not `=^`

http://jsfiddle.net/atdVN/

Comment: THANK YOU sir! That's humbling, one feels so powerless over that '5 o'clock' feeling sometimes :-)

Comment: @vector glad to help. :) honestly, it's a mistake anyone could make. :P  A fresh pair of eyes is always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [attribute contains prefix selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/).

```
  <a href="example.html" hreflang="english">will not be outlined</a>
  <script>
      $('a[hreflang|="en"]').css('border','3px dotted green');
  </script>
```